# Prove the language is not context-free?

Tags: finite-automata

How can you prove the language L given below is not context-free, I would like to know does my proof given below makes any sense, if not, what would be the correct method to prove?

L = {a^n b^n c^i|n ≤ i ≤ 2n}

I am trying to solve this language by contradiction. Suppose L is regular and with pumping length p such that S = a^p b^p c^p. Observe that S ∉ L. Since there must be a pumping cycle xy with length less than p, this can duplicate y which consists of some number of b to cause x(y^2)z to enter the language because the number of b exceeds the number of c by no longer bound by the given condition of i which is n ≤ i  ≥ 2n, therefore, we have contradiction and hence language L is not context-free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that the languages are not context free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954769/prove-that-the-languages-are-not-context-free)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is by contradiction. Assume the language is context-free. Then, by the pumping lemma for context-free languages, any string in L can be written as uvxyz where |vxy| < p, |vy| > 0 and for all natural numbers k, u(v^k)x(y^k)z is in the language as well. Choose a^p b^p c^(p+1). Then we must be able to write this string as uvxyz so that |vy| > 0. There are several possibilities to consider:

1. v and y consist only of a's. In this case, pumping in either direction causes the numbers of a's and b's to differ, producing a string not in the language; so this cannot be the case.
2. v and y consist only of a's and b's. In this case, pumping might keep the numbers of a's and b's the same, but pumping up will eventually cause the number of c's to be less than the number of a's and b's; so this cannot be the case.
3. v and y consist only of b's. This case is similar to (1) above and so cannot be a valid choice.
4. v and y consist only of b's and c's. Also similar to (1) and (3) in that pumping will cause the numbers of a's and b's to differ.
5. v and y consist only of c's. Pumping up will eventually cause there to be more c's than twice the number of a's; so this cannot be the case either.

No matter how we choose v and y, pumping will produce strings not in the language. This is a contradiction; this means our assumption that the language is context-free must have been incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it